# Error when installing a plugin in magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, installation

I am installing a plugin but when I say I get a permission error, how can I fix it?

I attached a screenshot of what I did to install it

[image: Magento]

Comment: You are invoking magento with the user named `daemon`. Magento wants to remove a cache directory, but this user does not have permissions to do so. Try to find the permissions and owner with `ls -al /var/www/html/var/`. If you do not know how to read the output, post it here in the question. Then, either run magento as the owner of the directory, or change the owner of the cache directories.

Answer (score 2):

try below command to give permission.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/*

sudo chmod -R 777 pub/*

sudo chmod -R 777 generated/*
```

Then run your command

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving permission to `var` folder

```
sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/
```

Also, you can set ownership and permissions to Magento root folder

```
cd magento2
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} +
find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} +
chmod u+x bin/magento
```

> To optionally enter all commands on one line, enter the following
>   assuming Magento is installed in /var/www/html/magento2:

```
cd /var/www/html/magento2 && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type f -exec chmod u+w {} + && find var generated vendor pub/static pub/media app/etc -type d -exec chmod u+w {} + && chmod u+x bin/magento
```

**Hope it helps.**